# SPFx WebPart Redux in Combination with ServiceScope - WebPartContext-Error

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

My WebPart makes use of Redux. My dataAction calls a Service (ServiceScope) to fetch data. Because my Service uses HTTPClient I send the WebPartContext as Parameter from WebPart to Action.

The dataAction:

```
export function getRecentChanges(filter: IFilter, context: WebPartContext) {  
  return (dispatch) => {
    var dataService: IRecentChanges<Array<IData>> = null;
    const serviceScope: ServiceScope = context.serviceScope.getParent();
      serviceScope.whenFinished((): void => {
         dataService = serviceScope.consume(RecentChanges.serviceKey as any) as IRecentChanges<Array<IData>>;
        var p1 = dataService.getRecentChanges(context, "", "");
        p1.then(data => {
          dispatch(loadRecentChangesSuccess(data));
          dispatch(dataLoadingCompleted());
        }).catch((reason: any) => {
          dispatch(resetErrorMessage());
      });
      });
  };
}
```

My WebPart will call the Redux-Action like so:

```
export default class RecentChangesWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IRecentChangesWebPartProps> {

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    var self = this;
    store.dispatch((dispatch) => {
      dispatch(getRecentChanges(null,self.context));
    });
    return super.onInit();
  }
....
```

When I run gulp bündle, Visual Studio Code complaints about the WebPart-Context.

> Error - typescript -
>   src/webparts/recentChanges/actions/dataActions.ts(42,46): error
>   TS2345: Argument of type 'WebPartContext' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'WebPartContext'.

Line and column from this message is pointing to:

```
dataService = serviceScope.consume(RecentChanges.serviceKey as any) as IRecentChanges<Array<IData>>;
```

Column 46 is the first e of RecentChanges.

Version from WebPart package.json:

```
"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.1",
"@types/react": "15.6.6",
"@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
"@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
"office-ui-fabric-react": "^5.55.3",
"react": "15.6.2",
"react-dom": "15.6.2"
```

So, What could cause the message "Argument of type 'WebPartContext' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WebPartContext'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved.

I used the terminal of visual studio code to get the versions of npm and node by calling: node -v and npm -v

I realized that my versions are may too old and updated node and npm to the latest versions and the error was gone.

Hope this helps others, too.